# Open different applications in part of screen using multi windowing

Tags: android, multi-window

I am going to use multi windowing feature in my project and I have question. Is it possible to have one application always open to the left of the screen (my application selector "A") which opens different applications on the remaining part of the screen ("B"). I know I can open new activity on the part of screen using multi windowing but what about separate applications?

```
It should look like this:
___________________
|   |              |
| A |     B        |
|   |              |
|___|______________|
```

It it kind of launcher but I need to launch every application on the second, bigger part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can open new activity on the part of screen using multi windowing but what about separate applications?

It will depend whether those applications support multi-windowing or not. If they do, you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` to request that it go in an adjacent window.

However, this is the user's device:

- The user can do whatever they want with those windows, including getting rid of them
- The OS and user control the sizes of those windows
- On freeform multiwindow devices (e.g., Chrome OS), the windows are not necessarily side by side